# External helper file for handlebars.js

Tags: node.js, gulp, handlebars.js

I'm running some Gulp tasks and using handlebars.js for html templating, but I'm struggling to get helper functions to work from an external js file... The [documentation here](http://handlebarsjs.com/) doesn't really explain how the external file should look, so I'm hoping someone can help me out.

Here's what I have

```js
/**** gulpfile.js ****/

var gulp = require('gulp');
var hb = require('gulp-hb');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp
        .src('./src/{,posts/}*.html')
        .pipe(hb({
            partials: './src/assets/partials/**/*.hbs',
            helpers: './src/assets/helpers/*.js',
            data: {
              people: [
                {firstName: "Yehuda", lastName: "Katz"},
                {firstName: "Carl", lastName: "Lerche"},
                {firstName: "Alan", lastName: "Johnson"}
              ]
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./web'));
});

/**** External js file .../helpers/helpers.js ****/

Handlebars.registerHelper('list', function(items, options) {
  var out = "<ul>";

  for(var i=0, l=items.length; i<l; i++) {
    out = out + "<li>" + options.fn(items[i]) + "</li>";
  }

  return out + "</ul>";
});
```

```html
<!-- Handlebars html template -->
{{#list people}}{{firstName}} {{lastName}}{{/list}}
```

Shoots out an error message:

```
[14:10:13] ReferenceError: Handlebars is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/helpers/src/assets/helpers/helpers.js:1:63)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at mapper (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/helpers/node_modules/gulp-hb/node_modules/handlebars-wax/node_modules/require-glob/src/require-glob.js:51:12)
at Array.map (native)
at mapReduce (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/helpers/node_modules/gulp-hb/node_modules/handlebars-wax/node_modules/require-glob/src/require-glob.js:87:4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**
Sorry, I should have looked at the docs more carefully.

You should add functions to helpers property in object you pass to

```
hb({
    helpers:{
         list: function (){}
    }
})
```

Or if you pass a path to helpers file, you just export object with functions, so you don't need access to HandleBars at all.

```
//helpers.js
module.exports = {
      list: function (){}
};
```

**Incorrect**
You need to require the gulp-hb module and use its property *handlebars*.

```
var HandleBars = require('gulp-hb').handlebars;

HandleBars.registerHelper(...);
```

Comment: Heya Molda, thanks heaps for the help... It's now shooting out "Error: Missing helper: "list"

Comment: Hey @Molda, a big thanks for the help. The update worked. Mind if I asked were you found the docs?

Comment: @WillW The best way to find docs for a module is to go to npmjs.com find the module and if the documentation is not already on that page then there should be either a link to docs or a link to github repo. Well that's how I do it :) but in this case I had to look into code of gulp-hb to find it has 2 dependencies, handlebars and handlebars-wax. The important one is handlebars-wax since that's a module where the object passed into `hb(...)` function is passed.

Comment: Cheers for the help @molda!